# ReactJs - Ao clicar em Link, a URL troca mas os componentes não são renderizados

Tags: react, react-navigation

Estou tentando fazer uma navegação entra páginas em um projeto ReactJS.

A versão do react é `18.1.0`

Estou usando o pacote `react-router-dom` versão `5.2.0`

No meu componente `App` tenho o seguinte código:

```
import React from 'react';
import Routes from './routes';
import './Global.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <Routes/>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Meu componente `Routes` é dessa forma:

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import Login from './pages/Login';
import Alunos from './pages/Alunos';
import NovoAluno from './pages/NovoAluno';

export default function Routes(){
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={Login} />
                <Route exact path="/alunos" component={Alunos} />
                <Route exact path="/aluno/novo/:alunoid" component={NovoAluno} />
            </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
}
```

Se eu acessar as rotas digitando manualmente na URL, todas elas funcionam e renderizam os componente corretamente.

Porem, no componente `Alunos` eu tenho um `Link` que ao clicar, deve trocar de tela, mas isso não acontece, ele apenas troca a URL mas se mantem na tela (ou seja, nao troca o componente renderizado na tela).

O link no componente `Alunos` está assim `<Link className='button' to="aluno/novo/0">Novo Aluno</Link>`

Estou esquecendo alguma coisa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bem, resumidamente existe um problema de compatibilidade entre o `react@18` e o `react-router-dom@5` https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/7870

Você pode solucionar o problema das seguintes formas:

1. Alterar a versão do `react-router-dom@5` para a
   `react-router-dom@6`.
2. Inserir um `<React.StrictMode>` dentro do BrowserRouter

..

```
<BrowserRouter>
<React.StrictMode>
...
</React.StrictMode>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: Vou marcar como resposta, o link do github ajudou muito. O que eu fiz foi fazer somente a opção dois que você falou. Eu retirei o React.StrictMode do index e add somente no componente routes dentro de BrowserRouter.